# Regarding transit visa for Thailand

Tags: visas, air-travel, transit, transit-visas

I am indian having indian passport I am traveling to Japan. I have a layover in Thailand please check do I need a transit visa for Thailand and how can I get
My flight details are Thai Airways Kolkata CCU India (2:00 IST 22 nd may) to Bangkok BKK layover of 17 h 55 m to NGO Japan (8:00 IST 23 rd May) .

Answer (score 1):

According to Timatic, the system used by airlines https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b, transit without a visa is available for passengers transiting through Bangkok (BKK) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 12 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

Information on how to apply for a transit visa is available on http://www.mfa.go.th/main/en/services/4908/15398-Issuance-of-Visa.html

Comment: Is it better to get a transit visa or apply for visa on arrival